# Notification Hub push issue with $InstallationId tag

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I'm using [azure-mobile-apps-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node) to register and send push notifications via GCM. I register notification clients using push.patchInstallation like this:

```
var updateOperation = [{
    'op': 'replace',
    'Path': '/tags',
    'Value': tags.join()
}];

push.patchInstallation(installationId, updateOperation, function (error, res) { /*...*/ };
```

And it works well, looking at the Notification Hub registrations, I see

```
<GcmRegistrationDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ETag>13</ETag>
    <ExpirationTime>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z</ExpirationTime>
    <RegistrationId>1234568266548022282-123456473823493176-1</RegistrationId>
    <Tags>$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID},location_1,location_2,location_3,userId:myaccount@domain.com</Tags>
    <GcmRegistrationId>SOME_ID</GcmRegistrationId>
</GcmRegistrationDescription>
```

However, if I try to push notifications using the tag "location_N", it never works. Have also tried with multiple devices both having registered to specific location_N and none of them gets the push updates.

I've determined this to be due to the *$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID}* that the azureMobile apps patchInstallation injects as first tag.

- If I use REST API and modify registration Tags to location_N, and send push to that tag, it works fine.
- If I send push to tag *$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID}*, push goes through to that specific device.
- If I use tag *$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID} || location_N*, only device with the installation ID gets the push notification.

Is this just limitation when using the Installation method, or is it a bug, or have I completely misunderstood something?

**EDIT 19.10.2017:**
I modified my code to use the Registration model, i.e.,

```
notificationHubService.gcm.createOrUpdateNativeRegistration(registrationId, installation.pushChannel, tags.join(), function(error, res) { /*...*/ }
```

which doesn't inject the $InstallationId to tags, but instead creates two registrations with same GcmRegistrationId, but with different Tags, one with the $InstallationId

```
<RegistrationId>REGID1</RegistrationId>
<Tags>$InstallationId:{SOMEGUID},_UserId:sid:SOMESID</Tags>
<GcmRegistrationId>GCMREGID</GcmRegistrationId>
```

and the other with just the tags I define in *createOrUpdateNativeRegistration*

```
<RegistrationId>REGID2</RegistrationId>
<Tags>location_1,location_2,location_3</Tags>
<GcmRegistrationId>GCMREGID</GcmRegistrationId>
```

With this I'm able to send push messages to my test devices using location_N tags (and also to specific device using the $InstallationId), so both registrations work. I have no idea why it creates two registrations as I don't have any calls to *notificationHubService.createRegistrationId* in any point, just single call to *createOrUpdateNativeRegistration*.

Comment: I would recommend you follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) for troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: That article doesn't discuss this issue, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid scenario. You should be able to push notifications using the location_N tag. Could you try 'test send' in portal.azure.com to verify that devices are selected for push notification?

Comment: Thank you confirming that it should work. However, regardless if I use Postman to send notification via REST, or use Azure Test Send, it will not find the tagged registrations IF the first tag is $InstallationId. Azure Test Send says: 'Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets.'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are using the **Installation** model, and a system tag `$InstallationId:[installationId]` is automatically added with your installation, you could send to this tag to target a specific device.

From your code, you are using the [JSON-Patch standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for updating your tags on the registration. You replaced your tags with a single string tag via `tags.join()`.

For replacing multiple tags for your installation, you need to specific your `updateOperation` as follows:

```html
var updateOperation = [{
    'op': 'replace',
    'Path': '/tags',
    'Value': tags //An array of tags.
}];
```

Moreover, you could try to read your installation and check your tags to narrow this issue.

Comment: I believe this won't change a thing, as regardless of how I do it, the end result is that the <Tags> contain comma separated list of tags (as you can see in OP). If the first tag is the $InstallationId:[installationId], none of the other tags work. If I use Registration model to set tags so that it will not contain $InstallationId, all tags work great!

Comment: From your test, it seems that it could only send push with tag `$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID}` when using the Installation model. Have you tried to retrieve your installation via code and check your valid tags?

Comment: Yes, fetching the installation shows that Tags are valid, i.e., <Tags>$InstallationId:{SOME_GUID},location_1,location_2,location_3,userId:myaccount@domain.com</Tags>, with the exception of the automatically injected $InstallationId of course, as it contains $ which is not a valid character in tags to begin with.